# Docker container export and importing it into image

Tags: docker

I have started using docker recently, Initially when I stared the docker image was 2-3 GB in size. I am saving the work done from the container into an image(s) so the image size have grown significantly(~6 GB). I want delete images while preserving the work done. When I export the container to gziped file, the size of that file is ~1 GB. Will it work fine if I delete the current image I have now(~6 GB) and create a new one from the gzipped file with docker import. The description of import command says it will create filesystem image, its docker image or something else ie I will be able to create containers from that image?

Comment: Can you add the `Dockerfile` you've been using to your question?  It'd be surprising for an image to unexpectedly become much larger when you `docker build` it.

Comment: The image was small initially, inside the container created from it I kept on copying sources,doing applications source builds,updates in build,running tests that created big logs, that I believe increased its size when commited the container to image, it seems like deleting files from inside the container does not reduce the size of image commited later, so I want to see if I will get everything functional when container is exported to local file and imported back

Comment: "I ran a bunch of stuff and committed it" is not a reproducible process.  The Docker [Get Started, Part 2: Containers](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) walks through the standard process of writing a `Dockerfile` and using that to build a custom image.  You should pretty much never use `docker commit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the image (see more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/)), for example:

```sh
docker save busybox > busybox.tar
```

Another alternative is to write a `Dokerfile` which contains all the instructions necessary to build your image. The main advantage is that this is a text file which can be versioned controlled hence, you can keep track of all the changes you made to your image. Another advantage is that you can deploy that image elsewhere without having to copy images across the system. For example, instead of copying a 1GB or 6GB image, you just need to copy the `DockerFile` and build the image in that new host. More details about the docker file can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)